# Conditional formula semi-relative row and relative column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet that I use as a calendar. Image of Google Sheet (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jusZs.png).

I am trying to create a conditional formula that grays out an entire day if the date is in the past, so cells B11 through B18 are gray if B11 is less than today.

What I have is this conditional formula:

Apply to range: B11:H18

Custom formula: `=isdate(B$11)*(B$11<today())`

which works for the week of 12/10 to 12/16.

For the next week, I have to change the custom formula to: `=isdate(B$19)*(B$19<today())`

And so on for following weeks.

What I had wanted to do was to have a custom formula that looked like:
`=isdate(B$ROW())*(B$ROW()<today())`

in the hopes that I could set different custom formula's up for each week but then have ROW() resolve to the first row of the range so I didn't have to manually edit the custom formula for each week I have in the calendar.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should be able to base it on the row. Try custom formula

```
=index(B$11:B,quotient(row()-11,8)*8+1)<today()
```

[image]

Comment: So Index is taking the range B$11 down to all of B, and finding the quotient of the row (sub 11 because the calendar is starting on row 11) with a divisor of 8 because there are 8 cells under each date, then multiplying by 9 to get to the date rows (row 11 gets 0*9, row 19 gets 1*9, etc.).  Col is defaulted to 0. So index then picks up each of the date cells. The application of the formula across the columns changes B$11:B to C$11:C, etc. for each subsequent column. Nice. Thank you!